# Ubuntu Stopping at Boot Screen

Tags: boot, package-management, synaptic

So, I was installing some packages via Synaptic. They were for my fan and hot keys. It froze durning installation, so I rebooted it, only to get stuck at the splash screen. I'm guessing it's just not loading the login panel. Any help?

I'm using a Dell Vostro 3450, Ubuntu 14.??

Pressing Crtl - Alt - F1  does nothing at the splash screen. I don't really know how to go into no-graphics mode.

Low-graphics mode seems unresponsive. The mouse does not show up, but it does do some hover effects. I was only able to get past the initial low-graphics warning before it stopped responding.

Answer (score 0):

On GRUB screen after BIOS Start-up

Try to repair files from system using recovery mode.

Something like:
Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.8.0-26-generic (recovery mode)

Comment: Already tried that, thanks for the tip though :/

Comment: Did you try Boot-repair from LiveCD/USB either ?

Comment: Don't have one, but I'm guessing that this is a graphics or startup issue. I don't really know though

Comment: I saw in another post that you got pre-installed Ubuntu on your Notebook Dell. Try to run LiveCD and do the same download package with Synaptic. If it runs fine, maybe your pre-installed Ubuntu could be the problem. Dell and another companies make sometimes very bad work with Linux as primary OS, unfortunately.

Comment: I got it from another guy who installed it, not Dell. I did not have this problem until it froze when running Synapse and trying to install a package. It then ceased to boot properly. But how exactly would I repair the files via recovery mode. I can successfully get into Recovery mode, but I am pretty clueless after that

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Grub menu during boot & add `nomodeset` parameter to the Linux (kernel) line. See instructions here: [Is the download live dvd image of ubuntu up to date?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461674/is-the-download-live-dvd-image-of-ubuntu-up-to-date/461686#461686)

It will load Ubuntu with less optimized graphics.

Comment: Did that, it still stops, but now it says "* speech-dispatcher disabled; edit/etc/default/speech-dispatcher